# Performance of RoboCopy when complex folder structure & files are to sync

Tags: windows, robocopy

I would require some recommendations from you about the challenge that I am currently facing.

Background : There are Network Attached Storage in the US and India Office. All the data currently resides in the US Storage facility. I am trying to sync certain folders from the US storage to the India Storage. I would like to sync data pretty much in real time. There are close to *30,000 folders and 100,000 files*.

I explored lot of softwares which can do this but getting those softwares in the company is a difficult option. Hence I am looking at options like **RoboCopy**, **XCopy**, **RichCopy**, **Synctoy** etc. Following are my requirements

1. Data Sync should be in real time
2. If the file is accessed by 2 or more users at the same time, then Sync should not corrupt the file. More importantly it should not create multiple versions of the same file. This is the reason why **DFSR** does not suit.

RoboCopy gives me the ability to monitor the folders and copy the data automatically and also skip the file when it is opened by someone.

```
RoboCopy "\\Server1\Folder" "\\Server2\Folder" *.xyz /z /mir /mot:30 /log:test.log
```

SyncToy and RichCopy do not monitor the changes in real time.

XCopy's speed and options are limited.

I have the following questions:

1. How is the performance of RoboCopy when complex folder structure exists ?
2. Is there any other software which can accomplish this? Preferably from Microsoft.
3. How long does RoboCopy monitor the changes to the files and folders ? Does it keep running until the command prompt is closed ?
4. How does timestamp play a role when the NAS are located in 2 different time zones?